# Axis interpretation in 3D Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, axis-labels

*I am using the following example to understand the working of axis in 3D arrays in Numpy.*

```
a = np.array([[9],[9],[8]])
b = np.array([[1],[4],[6]])

print(np.stack([a,b],axis=0) 
>>>
array([[[9],
        [9],
        [8]],

       [[1],
        [4],
        [6]]])

print(np.stack([a,b],axis=1) 
>>>
array([[[9],
        [1]],

       [[9],
        [4]],

       [[8],
        [6]]])

print(np.stack([a,b],axis=2) 
>>>
array([[[9, 1]],

       [[9, 4]],

       [[8, 6]]])
```

I am able to understand how axis=0 and axis=1 work. Can anyone explain how axis=2 works with pictorial representation as it is done for 2D arrays?

For reference

```
print(np.stack([a,b],axis=0.shape)  #(2,3,1)
print(np.stack([a,b],axis=1.shape)  #(3,2,1)
print(np.stack([a,b],axis=2.shape)  #(3,1,2)
```

Comment: I don't see what is unclear, you have two `(3,1)` arrays. The dimension on which you `stack` is added. This is why you have the `2` in position 0,1,2, if you`stack` on 0,1,2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can see 3D numpy arrays as data cube.
Let's suppose we have an np.array A.
`(z, y, x) = np.shape(A)`. You notice that the z dimensions corresponds to the indices 0.
Your array A is simply z 2d array of dimensions (y, x) that you stack together.
It explains why `A[0,:,:]` is a 2d array.
Axis = 2 simply points out that you consider 2d arrays stacked on the z direction!